# PhP code won't assign properly after successful connection to database

Tags: php

My code is not assigning properly. The only one working is the first if in the following code.

I tried to assign them with an or in a single if, but same thing.

```
$nomClient = "";
$telClient = "";
$noClient = "";



if(($client = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false){
    $nomClient = $client["NOM_CLIENT"];
    $erreur = "";
}else{
    $erreur = "no client";

}

if(($tel = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false){
        $telClient = $tel["TEL_CLIENT"];
        $erreur = "";
    }else{
        $erreur = "no phone_number";
    }


if(($nocli = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false){
        $noClient = $nocli["NO_CLIENT"];
        $erreur = "";
    }else{
        $erreur = "no client_number";
    }
```

My current result is that the name is showed (in my print that is not showed here in this code)
also the error returned is the last one 'no client_number'.

if the last if is tel_client, then the error would be no_phone_number.

So basically only the first if is taken into consideration here.

I need to return the first row of my sql database with no error message. I'm not sure how to assign my 2 last ifs for the phone number and the client number.

Comment: Not familiar with the oci API, but I’d assume `oci_fetch_array` fetches the next row in the result set. You don’t want to call that again and again. You only need to call it once.

Comment: I see, but im still struggling with assigning telclient to tel and nomClient to client

Answer (score 2):

[oci_fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php) retrieves a **row**, not a **column**:

> Returns the next row from a query as an associative or numeric array

So every time you invoke it and grab a different column it doesn't belong to the same row. If you get `no client_number` that means you have two clients. You're currently getting the name of the first one and the phone number of the second one.

- If you expect a single row (as in "get client by ID"), you only need the first conditional; `$client` already contains all columns, as `var_dump($client);` will tell you. You also need to fix your query because it's returning *two* rows.
- If you expect several rows (as in "get all clients") you need a loop:

  ```
  while (($client = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) !== false) {
      $nomClient = $client["NOM_CLIENT"];
      $telClient = $tel["TEL_CLIENT"];
      $noClient = $nocli["NO_CLIENT"];
      // Now do something with your data: it'll be overwritten on next iteration
  }
  ```